# i want to manage category in magento

Tags: magento

i want to manage category in magento but i have one error adding category that time lets see my error and give me right answer i show my error Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\magento\lib\Varien\Data\Tree\Dbp.php on line 332
i give my code

```
 public function loadEnsuredNodes($category, $rootNode)
{

    $pathIds = $category->getPathIds();
    $rootNodeId = $rootNode->getId();
    $rootNodePath = $rootNode->getData($this->_pathField);

    $select = clone $this->_select;
    $select->order($this->_table.'.'.$this->_orderField . ' ASC');

    if ($pathIds) {
        $condition = $this->_conn->quoteInto("$this->_table.$this->_idField in (?)", $pathIds);
        $select->where($condition);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

get/set functions is feature of varien object. your error says; rootNode is not a varien object.